# Android in app purchase purchase/refund/sub expired events

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've just implemented and tested on my phone Android In-App purchase with API V2 (because I also need to implement subscriptions). Actually the app is not published but only in draft status.

I've already tested purchase and it works perfectly.

I've some question about the notification system that I actually don't understand.

1) First question

I have many devices with the same Google account (so they I share the same purchased items). I just purchased correctly an item from my app on device A but it has not been notified to the other device B.

Have I to wait some notification from Google Play on device B or it will never happen?
If I'm in the second case, which is the solution? Make a RESTORE_TRANSACTION everytime the app is started?

**UPDATE SOLUTION FOR PROBLEM 1**: I think that the problem was that my google account was also a test account in my developer console. I actually tested it removing the account from test list and worked well.

2) Second question

I've tried also the refund system. I've refunded my purchased item (a managed one) from developer console but I never got the REFUND event. Why?

If I disinstall the app and install it again the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS is telling me that the in-app I refunded is still in PURCHASED state. What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE**: the subscription has been REFUNDED well (not expired but just refunded). The managed in-app purchase instead is still in status PURCHASED but on the developer console I've refunded and cancelled the order. Why is still in purchase state?

3) Third question

My user make a subscription and than it expires. Is google going to send me the SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED event to my app or have I always to do a RESTORE_TRANSACTION?

4) Last question

I've refunded a subscription and it sent to me the event of refund. Actually the subscription is valid until the end of month so I think that I need to give the user the subscription-service since the end of the month and I think that after it, if the user won't re-charge I will get a SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRES event.

Am I right?

Thanks, Emanuele.

**UPDATE**: updated with partial answer, another question and more details.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I made some steps.

My purchase google account was also a Test account in my developer console. This prevented (I think) the NOTIFY events to be sent.

Now I purchased a new item from the market and it appeared to all my devices.

I still have other problems and question (I will update the main question)

**UPDATE**: for managed in-app purchase (not subscription) if you refund an user (not cancel order but just refund) this will not send any event to your application (at least it seems so). If you cancel the order (from developer console) it will send a CANCELED event.